# FB.login does not create the cookie immediately

Tags: facebook

I as using FB Connect to authenticate users on my site.

```
var selfcloseUrl = getAidEngineUrl() + "/selfclose.html";
        FB.login(callbackFunctionParameter, {
            scope: FbPermissions,
            redirect_uri: selfcloseUrl
        });
```

where callbackFunctionParameter is a function that redirect the user like this:

```
function(){
            document.location = "/members/view/quickFbConnect";
        });
```

for some reason the facebook cookie is not available in the quickFbConnect action.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why.

I do know that you shouldn't mess with the Facebook cookies.  Doing so is asking to get burned.  They are not intended for direct access or interaction with your code.  They are an "implementation detail" on which you should not take a dependency.  Whatever you are trying to do with the cookies there is a better (supported) way to do it.

> Cookies used by the SDKs
>
> Our JavaScript and PHP SDKs support a common cookie format that allows you to access Facebook Platform from both client and server side code in a seamless fashion. Previously, we documented this cookie format. This resulted in many apps and SDKs taking a dependency on it. We would like to consider this cookie format to be an implementation detail so that we can make changes for security or other reasons, and advise apps not to take a direct dependency on the format. Rather than attempting to parse our cookies, we recommend that you use one of the above supported SDKs or use OAuth endpoints to directly authenticate and authorize users. Our Authentication Guide highlights how to perform authentication and authorization directly.

Source:  https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/624/

Comment: Pat without that cookie being set it is impossible for the PHP SDK to actually get the user's information.

Comment: Sorry if you don't like the answer but I don't think you can argue with the reference.  The way Facebook wants you to do it is to get an accesstoken from the Javascript SDK, use server-side OAuth authentication to get a code and exchange it for an accesstoken, or use client-side OAuth to get an accesstoken.  Bottom line you should get an accesstoken from some source other than directly reading the cookie if you want it to be reliable and supported.  You are already  seeing the negative side-effects of trying to read the cookie directly:  it is not always there when you want or expect it.

Comment: Also you did not state that PHP or the Facebook PHP SDK is part of your question.  Maybe your question should really be: "why do I need to reauthenticate after a page redirect when using the Facebook Javascript SDK in conjunction with the Facebook PHP SDK" or whatever your real problem is.  I suspect the answer will still be something along the lines of "you are doing it wrong"